# jQuery code wont work in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I use `jQuery1.11.1` and execute this code:

```
  var links= $("#custom-menu").find("li").find("a");
    links.each(function(){
         if($(this).attr("href")==="#openModal")
        {
            $(this).on("click",function(event){
                alert("Click event called on li");
                $("#openModal").css("visibility","visible").fadeIn();
                alert("Is the table showing now");
            });
        }   
    });
```

This works in IE8 but it does not work in IE7,nothing happens when I click the `li`.

## EDIT:

I have narrowed it down,the control does not go into this block:

```
 if($(this).attr("href")==="#openModal")
```

Comment: In code you have a click event on `a`, not on `li`.

Comment: Do you have a version online somewhere where we can view the result as it should be?

Comment: @panther Its like a menu,originally they are using `css transistions` to display it,but does not work with `IE7` so,I have to change it to use `visibility` and `fadeIn/fadeOut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that an internal/in-page href attribute on IE7 looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/mypage#openModal
```

instead of `#openModal`

So,instead of using this

```
 if($(this).attr("href")==="#openModal")
```

I used:

```
 if($(this).attr("href")==="#openModal" || $(this).attr("href") ===(window.location.href+"#openModal"))
```

Comment: Please try `this.hash == '#openModal'` in your if condition, it should work in IE7 as well, since the parts of the `href`, like `hash`, `host`, `port`, ...  are properties of the <A> tag in the DOM API